# subtract two values in the field

Tags: python, function, for-loop

I am using python.

There are two columns. columns A and B. I want to reduce the value in column A and B when the save button in the press

this my code

But what happens when I press the save button. value to 0

```
def _tot_get_deposit(self, cr, uid, ids, name, arg, context=None):
    res = {}
    for deposit in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        sum = 0.0
        sum = A - B
        return sum
    return res
```

Comment: The indention of you Python code is not correct.

Comment: What are `A` and `B`? You loop through `deposits`, but don't do anything with the deposit values. Your code sample will throw an error: NameError: name 'A' is not defined.

Comment: `sum` is a bad choice of name as it also happens to be the name of a built-in function. `A` and `B` are what exactly? And you return the first `A - B` or an empty dict... I don't get what you're trying to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you need to read more about how functions work.

once you `return` anything, the function will end.

you can not itterate over anything and return multiple values within a function.

try saving them locally in the function, and then at the end returning a list/dict/tuple with all the results.

for instance... i think your code could be written:

```
def _tot_get_deposit(self, cr, uid, ids, name, arg, context=None):
    res = {}
    results = []
    for deposit in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        sum = 0.0
        sum = A - B
        results.append( sum )
    return (res,results)
```

this will create a list of "sum" which is then added to your dict "res" and then returned. together as a tuple.

Comment: there are much more efficient ways to do this, but i think that this is only part of your code, and i wanted to provide an answer that is simple enough to understand with your declared limited understanding of python.

Comment: Good explanation. Minor quibble, `res` is never used, so why include/return it?

Comment: it can compatible with openerp ? I used OpenERP